# OSRM : allow U-turns

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I've updated some nodes in OpenStreetMap to add the highway=turning_circle attribute, but OSRM won't let vehicles turn around.

I want to allow scholar bus to turn around in some remote country area, where they will turn around at the kids houses after picking them up.

Here's an exemple : https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/115162#map=21/45.50478/1.30020

The bus coming from the north turns around in front of the house.

Is there any other tag to add  to OSM to make OSRM allow vehicles to turn around ?

Answer (score 0):

After talking with someone who developed OSRM profiles, OSM tags can not be used out of the box to accomplish this.
We're making several requests to OSRM instead of one, cutting the journey at some points where we want U-turns to be allowed.